# Laravel: Editing an object through iteration?

Tags: laravel

In my controller, I have a variable `$products` that I get from a query to the DB

`$products = Product::with('customer', 'variants')->find($orderId);`

I am returning that as JSON to my frontend which looks like this:

```
"products":[
      {
         "id":414,
         "order_id":286,
         "variant": {
               "color": "green"
          },
          "price": 99
      },
      {
         "id":415,
         "order_id":287,
         "variant": {
               "color": "red"
          },
          "price": 99
      }
]
```

In the Controller, I am trying to change the price color to be an empty string so I attempted it by doing this but keep getting the error "trying to get property of non-object`.  What am I doing wrong?

```
            $products = Product::with('customer', 'variants')->find($orderId);

            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $product->variant->color = "blue";
            }
```

Comment: You are loading 'variants' (plural) relation and accessing 'variant' (single)

Comment: what's the relationship between `products` and `variants`?

Answer (score 0):

using `first()` you just will get one item, and not a collection of items.

To get the products try use `get()` instead of `fisrt()`.

And to edit the object in the iteration, if `variant` is an Eloquent Model and has a relationship to `Product`, you can use:

```php
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->variant->color = "blue";
    $product->variant->save();
}
```

Comment: thanks!  I actually need a collection of items though to pass to the frontend.